# Android Data from external storage into File object

Tags: android, file, pdf, local-storage

I have an pdf file which is stored here `/data/data/com.blabla/cache/blabla.pdf151.tmp` and need this as `File pdf = new File()`. Everything i tried gave me an Null pointer.

Comment: path you are using is temporary file not actual pdf file try to use file with proper extenion like .pdf

Comment: so i just split the string to /data/data/com.blabla/cache/blabla.pdf ?

Comment: no buddy its not like that path is temp value of PDF not actual pdf use another file whose extension is .pdf only not pdf/teas.tmp

Comment: well, i need exactly this file. It is downloaded from an API and cached.

Comment: then that file is not fully Downloaded from API